# Monthly Salesforce Reports - How to exclude any records that were present in previous reports?

Tags: excel, power-automate, salesforce-lightning

I've been asked to provide a monthly report that includes events coming up between the current date and the next 60 days. The initial report is straightforward, but in subsequent reports, the user would only like to see any events that have been added since the previous monthly report. These events could be added at any time, so it's likely there will be events added in June over the next few weeks that were not in the initial report. Those, as well as any that are new due to the date parameters (between report date and the following 60 days) would make up all future reports. I'm attempting to do this using exports from Salesforce and inserting in an Excel table.

I attempted to get this set up in Excel, using a table to store the initial data set, adding a couple of columns that auto-populate the date any new items are inserted, but that's where I got stuck. I'm not sure how to go about only inserting rows for events that don't already exist in the table (by event name, as they're all unique).

Comment: How about adding all the events and then removing duplicates?